# Sharing Swift UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to writing in Swift and I am trying to write up a little game. I have gotten most bits done through searching and debugging but I just can't get the UIActivityViewController to work.

I have done the following:

in GameViewController.swift

```html
func screenshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 1.0)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
}
```

and

```html
func shareString(string: String, url: NSURL, image: UIImage) {
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [string, url, image], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

then in GameScene.swift I have set up:

```html
protocol GameSceneDelegate {
    func screenshot() -> UIImage
    func shareString(string: String, url: NSURL, image: UIImage)
}
```

then set up a variable
var gameSceneDelegate = GameSceneDelegate.self

and then tried to call the functions

```html
func share() {
        
        let urlString = "http://www.google.com"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let screenshot = gameSceneDelegate.screenshot
        let initialTextString = "OMG! I scored \(score) points"
        gameSceneDelegate.shareString(initialTextString, url: url!, image: screenshot)
}
```

But when I try to call the last function line:
gameSceneDelegate.shareString(initialTextString, url: url!, image: screenshot)

I get this error: "Extra argument in call"

Where am I going wrong, I can't seem to understand why the shareString can't take 3 arguments when there are clearly three in the definition of the function.

Comment: where is 'score', has it been defined?

Comment: yeah, score is defined and works fine
variable is set    var score = 0

Comment: updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

in your function declaration you have no optionals, yet when calling the function you are force-unwrapping the url- try not making it an optional

EDIT:

I have encountered this error when the compiler can't figure out what is wrong- it could be something on another line above which has a type wrongfully assigned (like a dictionary in an array type, or using a constant that no longer exists). I would suggest reordering your function and see if the same error occurs on a different line.

Comment: just tried but I still get the same error. I also just tried removing the URL part of the function completely and just having the text and the image, but still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

```
let screenshot = gameSceneDelegate.screenShot
```

creates a variable of type `()->UIImage` i.e. a function. 
You need to evaluate the delegate function like this:

```
let screenshot = gameSceneDelegate.screenShot()
```

This will create a variable of type `UIImage` as you intend